# Permutations and Combinations in word problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

1. How many 4 digit numbers can be formed from the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 if each digit can only be used once?
2. There are 11 horses running at The Meadows Race Track.  The horses pay out for the horses coming in first, second and third.  If a customer selects all three (called a trifecta) there is a bonus payout.  How many different trifecta tickets are there for this race?

For 1: There are 7 different digits, so it would use the permutation formula, making it 7!(7-4)! which equals 840? Is this correct?

For 2: there are 11 horses, will this be a combination formula? Not sure.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{7!}{(7 - 4)!}$?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on the first.

On the second, while I'm not too familiar with pony races, to my understanding, for a trifecta, you choose three horses, and must determine which comes in first, second and third, though the question makes this somewhat ambiguous. If you also decide the order, it is a permutation, $ (11)_3 $, but if not, it's a combination, $ \binom{11}{3}$.